# Creating an aggregate columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':["A", "A", "B", "B"], 'var1':[2, 3, 1, 5],'a1_bal':[1,2,3,4], 'a1c_bal':[10,22,36,41], 'b1_bal':[1,2,33,4], 'b1c_bal':[11,22,3,4], 'm1_bal':[15,2,35,4]})
df
    ORDER   var1    a1_bal  a1c_bal  b1_bal   b1c_bal   m1_bal
0   A       2       1       10       1        11        15
1   A       3       2       22       2        22         2
2   B       1       3       36       33       3         35
3   B       5       4       41       4        4          4
```

I want to create new columns as below:

```
a1_final_bal = sum(a1_bal, a1c_bal)
b1_final_bal = sum(b1_bal, b1c_bal)
m1_final_bal = m1_bal (since we only have m1_bal field not m1c_bal, so it will renain as it is)
```

I don't want to hardcode this step because there might be more such columns as "c_bal", "m2_bal", "m2c_bal" etc..

My final data should look something like below

```
    ORDER   var1    a1_bal  a1c_bal  b1_bal   b1c_bal   m1_bal   a1_final_bal  b1_final_bal  m1_final_bal
0   A       2       1       10       1        11        15       11             12           15
1   A       3       2       22       2        22         2       24             24           2
2   B       1       3       36       33       3         35       38             36           35
3   B       5       4       41       4        4          4       45             8            4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. I am not sure if its exactly what you are looking for, but I think it should work.

```
dfforgroup = df.set_index(['ORDER','var1']) #Creates MultiIndex
dfforgroup.columns = dfforgroup.columns.str[:2] #Takes first two letters of remaining columns
df2 = dfforgroup.groupby(dfforgroup.columns,axis=1).sum().reset_index().drop(columns = 
['ORDER','var1']).add_suffix('_final_bal') #groups columns by their first two letters and sums the columns up
df = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1) #concatenates new columns to original df
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?